# How can I find out the current version of the CIVICRM database schema

Tags: civicrm

How can I find out the current version of the civicrm database schema?

Comment: Can you please elaborate - Answered correctly below.

Answer (score 6):

Look in the *civicrm_domain* table for the column *version* - that'll tell you what version the database is in.  (It's updated as one of the last steps in the upgrade process.)

```
SELECT version FROM civicrm_domain
```

If you have multiple CiviCRM domains running from the same data set, you'll see multiple entries, but for 99% of organizations, there'll just be the one result.

Meanwhile, if you want to see the codebase version (hopefully they're the same), it's in your civicrm directory in the file *civicrm-version.php* and displayed at the bottom of each page in the back end of CiviCRM.

Comment: Thanks, but this returns the version of the civiCRM plugin not the version of the database schema. For example associated with the upgrades are MySQL upgrade scripts. I have an civiCRM database and I am trying to find out where on the database upgrade version path it is.

Comment: You need to elaborate on what you mean by database schema.  There is no version specific.  there is a version of the app in the db and code base bversion.

Comment: the database versions are numbered like the codebase versions.  an upgrade can fail somewhere along the line, but the only way of figuring that out is to review the upgrade queries and see what's been done (i.e. has this new column been added? is there an option group named X?)

You can review the query templates in CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/sql; each has the number of the version it's upgrading to.